# Adding Mulitple table rows into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, multirow

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4S0F.png)  is a table for a challan. On clicking the "Add Product" Button, a new row is added to the table.

My issue here is that how should I create a table in MySQL Database so that I can add data from multiple rows into the database table.

Here is the code for the addition of row into the table:

order.php

```
<?php

require('../config.php');
$j = isset($_POST['j'])? $_POST['j']: '';
?>

<tr style="text-align: center;" id="products">
  <td><?php echo $j; ?></td>
  <td><select class="form-control productID" name="code" style="width: 429px;">
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<option id='".$row['code']."' value='".$row['code']."'>".$row['pname']."</option>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='hsnNo$j' readonly>"; ?></td>

  <td><?php echo "<input type='text' name='qty$j' readonly>"; ?></td>
  <td class="coljoin"><input type="number" format="2" name="amount"></td>
  <td>
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
$('.productID').change(function(){
  var code = $(this).val();
  console.log(code);
  var dataString = 'code='+code;

  $.ajax({
    url: "getProdDets.php",
    type: "post",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response){
      var Vals = JSON.parse(response);
      $("input[name='hsnNo<?php echo $j; ?>']").val(Vals.hsnNo);
      $("input[name='qty<?php echo $j; ?>']").val(Vals.qty);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

How should I design the table in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You should create table like this :-

```
$create = "CREATE TABLE tbltable (
column_one varchar (20) NOT NULL,
column_two int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
column_three int NOT NULL,
column_four varchar (15) NOT NULL,
column_five year
)";
```

Comment: How will I be able to add data from multiple rows to this query? Can you answer with respect to the code mentioned in the question?

Comment: what are the names of fields that you want to insert into table?

Comment: Its mentioned in the image.